# как в java реализовать функции передвижении фигуры после rotate?

Tags: java, swing

Как переместить фигуру в заданном направление?То есть имеется фигура, которая имеет определенную длину,, шага " и нужно переместить ее в заданном направлении.
Поворот фигуры реализовываю с помощью        `g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle),x,y)` .

Как дальше использовать координаты фигуры, что бы правильно переместить фигуру в нужном направлении?

Comment: разобрался. как удалить вопрос не знаю